# Add a variable for current URL to static block/page CMS

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, variables

I see that I can insert base url but how can I extend this list to include current URL?

So instead of `{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}` something that pulled in the current page URL and I could go from there?  I use the same static block on multiple products and I need this feature.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try using a relative link instead?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't - all my relative links are converted in the CMS so that if I'm on www.mydomain.com/about-us and I have a link in the CMS <a href="/our-team">link</a> then it will direct a user to www.mydomain.com/our-team and not www.mydomain.com/about-us/our-team.

Comment: Instead of "<a href="/our-team">link</a>", try using "<a href="our-team">link</a>" instead? :)

Comment: Thanks but the way our store is set up, both will go to www.mydomain.com/our-team - I really just need to know if I can set up a variable to use that will get and print the current URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add:

```
{{store _direct="url-key-here"}}
```

And this will get the url to the page that you put in the url key to. So if your cms page is `/blah` then simply add `{{store _direct="blah"}}`